# How do I use a Roland J-6 as a MIDI input device on a Roland MC-707?

Tags: synthesizer, midi-controller-keyboard

I'm embarrassingly clueless about this kind of thing but generally try to work things out independently. I've hit a brick wall here though.

I have a Roland J-6 and a Roland MC-707. I'd like to use the J-6 as a midi input device on the MC-707. I've tried the following:

1. J-6 USB-C to MC-707 USB. Didn't expect this to work and it proved to be the case.
2. J-6 MIDI OUT to MC-707 MIDI IN via a converter cable. This was advised by the folks where I bought the MC-707. This doesn't seem to work.
3. J-6 USB-C to Macbook and MC-707 USB to Macbook with J-6 OUT configured as MC-707 IN via MIDI Studio. This didn't work, thankfully.

Would anyone be able to put me out of my misery and translate into dummy-speak the steps I need to take to get this setup working?

The Roland MC-707 firmware version is 1.82.

Note: The converter (TRS 3.5mm to MIDI 5 Pins DIN) connects the J-6 3.5mm midi out port to the MC-707 midi in port via a midi cable.

Comment: The converter (TRS 3.5mm to MIDI 5 Pins DIN) connects the J-6 3.5mm midi out port to the MC-707 midi in port via a midi cable. Regarding configuration, the J-6, using [SHIFT]+[MENU] then [Ch], is configured to use channel 1. Likewise, the MC-707 is configured to accept input from channel 1 via [SHIFT]+[Knob Assign], then [SET], then [MIDI], then finally [MIDI Rx Auto Channel] to CH1. I expect my issue may be with how I am interpreting the software configuration instructions.